# tikz: smooth curve and arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a smooth curve in tikz that has an arrow tip both at the "beginning" and at the "ending".
It works fine when I add an arrow tip at the ending only (black curve below). However, when also specifying an arrow tip at the beginning the shape of the curve changes considerably and looks bumpy (red curve below):

[image]

How can I add the arrow tip at both sides and still have the shape of the black curve?

The code which I have used so far is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[
    every node/.style = {
        draw            = green,
        fill            = green,
        inner sep       = 0pt,
        circle,
        minimum size    = 2pt,
        font            = \footnotesize,
}]

\node   (A1)    at (30:3.00cm){};
\node   (A2)    at (35:9.00cm){};
\node   (A3)    at (125:4.00cm){};

\end{scope}

\draw[thick,black] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};
\draw[-Latex,thick,black] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};
\draw[Latex-Latex,thick,red,dashed] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the `bending` library:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,bending} %new code

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[
    every node/.style = {
        draw            = green,
        fill            = green,
        inner sep       = 0pt,
        circle,
        minimum size    = 2pt,
        font            = \footnotesize,
}]

\node   (A1)    at (30:3.00cm){};
\node   (A2)    at (35:9.00cm){};
\node   (A3)    at (125:4.00cm){};

\end{scope}

\draw[thick,black] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};
\draw[-Latex,thick,black] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};
\draw[Latex-Latex,thick,red,dashed] plot [smooth,tension=1] coordinates {(A1) (A2) (A3)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then it works.

[image]

Comment: it is pretty unusual to use `scope` for define styles ... and also use `pgfplots` when the `tikz` is sufficient :-)

Comment: I agree, but why are you telling this to me? I just reused the code provided by the original poster : )

Comment: Right, I will replace $scope$ ... $pgfplots$ is required for the rest of my document, that's how it made it inot the MWE.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to $bending$. Unfortunately, it shortens the red path too much with the $-Latex$ arrow tip. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: well, I didn't addressed comment specifically to you :-).  More serious: I observe, that dashed line is draw different, it start/ends far from start/end coordinates.

Comment: I didnt' notice the the path was shortened... It does not happen replacing `Latex` with `>` and also if `smooth` is removed, uhmmmm...

Comment: It seems to be bug here.